# How to modify my authenticated user in a WebSocket?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, websocket

I have this WebSocket endpoint:

```
@MessageMapping(USER_LOCATION)
public void sendLocation(@RequestBody Location location, Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
    LOCATION_SERVICE.sendUserLocation(user, location);
}
```

As you can see, I need access to the authenticated User to the WebSocket.
According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html)

> WebSockets reuse the same authentication information that is found in the HTTP request when the WebSocket connection was made.

And the problem is, while the WebSocket connection is open, the `User` information is likely to be changed. But, as the authentication information is from the HTTP request, that information could be outdated.

One solution is updating the `User` object used with the Repository, this way

```
@MessageMapping(USER_LOCATION)
public void sendLocation(@RequestBody Location location, Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
    user = USER_SERVICE.findById(user.getId()); // <-- Repository updating
    LOCATION_SERVICE.sendUserLocation(user, location);
}
```

But, this endpoint expects a big traffic, so that would traduce in a big amount of unnecessary database calls, reducing performance and increasing monetary cost.

Is there any way to update the `Authentication` object without acceding to the database every time that endpoint is called and accessing it only when the user is updated?

### Why do I need this endpoint?

My application has real-time location of each user. So, when any user opens the application the WebSocket connection is established and the client sends their location periodically (every 2 seconds). That location sending is not expected to finish until the user terminates the app. These locations are stored in a `HashMap` which acts like a buffer, where all the users and locations are stored:

```
private final Map<Long, UserLocation> USER_LOCATION_BUFFER;
```

When the client wants to access to the users in a specific location, access to that buffer. Not to the database.

This buffer is modified with the method shown before `LOCATION_SERVICE.sendUserLocation()`, this way:

```
public void sendUserLocation(User user, Location location) {
    USER_LOCATION_BUFFER.put(user.getId(), new UserLocation(user, location));
}
```

So, if in this time the user modify it's information (for example, changes their profile photo) the changes won't be shown to the other users until the user finishes the app and opens it again. Because the controller method `sendLocation` will override the user with the one which was established in the WebSocket connection.

### Is this a XY problem?

According to what @JimGarrison proposed at the comments, this could be a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). So, I'm open to hear if I'm facing the problem wrong.

The decisiones that made me opt for this solutions were:

**I don't want to access to the database every time I have to retrieve a user from the buffer**

This is because this retrieving happens with very frequently (is also periodically) and it would traduce to a big amount of database calls and most of them unnecessary (exactly the same way as in my proposed solution).

**The expected amount of users is not high**

This is not any surprise. As in any other new application, I aspire to start with a number of users in the order of thousands, if I'm very lucky. So, I think that the cost (talking about RAM, price, etc.) of having that buffer, will be smaller than accessing to the database in every call.

Comment: _"while the WebSocket connection is open, the User information is likely to be changed"_ - WHY?  Basic security requires that you open a new connection with the correct credentials.  I suspect this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Hello @JimGarrison, thanks for answering. I've updated my post according what you've said to identify if this is a XY Problem.